# GET request not working in postman, but POST request works

Tags: express, postman

Trying to call GET and POST request with Postman:

```
app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
  res.send("GET reqest");
});

app.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  res.send("POST request");
});
```

for POST request it works fine and i get "POST request" as a response. But for the GET request i get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /user</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you define two HTTP methods for the same route? It might be the issue with ordering of the methods in run time, so as a result the post method works fine as it's in the bottom. So, try putting the get method bottom of the post method, and see is that works

Comment: No still not working, actually i had this issue with GET request when fetching data from MongoDB, so POST request always works and saves the data then displays the result, but GET request dont, Always get this html response with 404 not found status, so this was just a test on the App.js file to check if the problem comes from the code or Postman. I think it come from Postman, its so frustrating haha

Comment: I mean if it was an end point error the post request wouldnt work either right ?